# Is NaCl precipitation possible in this mixture?

Tags: acid-base

Consider the following mixing of solutions:
$$\ce{HCl(aq) + NaOH(aq) -> NaCl(aq) + H2O(l)}$$
My chemistry book says that this equation is quite correct, especially in the sense that $\ce{NaCl}$ is always completely dissolved.

Naturally, I'm trying to prove it wrong. I read [online](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Introductory_Chemistry/Introductory_Chemistry_(CK-12)/16%3A_Solutions/16.03%3A_Saturated_and_Unsaturated_Solutions) that we can put at most 36g of salt into 100g water for it to dissolve completely. I also read on a [different site](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/21615094/) that even by conventional means, one may produce a hydrochloric acid solution with 37 wt %. This sounds about as much as the previous number, but 36g per 100g *solution* would be a much larger proportion. Then, [apparently](https://www.scienceforums.net/topic/40019-making-a-highly-conc-naoh-solution/) we can dissolve 111g sodium hydroxide in 100g of water.

So the question is: Can't I then produce highly concentrated solutions of sodium hydroxide and hydrochloric acid, so that upon mixing the two, some salt solidifies, because the resulting amount of salt is larger than what would be admissible in a saturated salt solution?

Comment: There is no law forbidding that. As for the details, I encourage you to finish the calculations that you just started. Take as much of the first solution as to contain one mole of HCl...

Comment: You're not ready for this kind of heat…

Comment: @Martin-マーチン could you clarify?

Comment: Highly concentrated acid + highly concentrated base -> a lot of heat of neutralisation + (maybe what's left of a) neutral solution

Comment: I see, so you're saying it's going to explode.

Comment: It won't exactly *explode*, but boiling of something like that...

Comment: Correction of the textbook statement:  **If HCl + NaOH neutralization is being performed by a chemist with common sense, NaCl always remains dissolved.** // There are very few rules in chemistry that have status of non-breakable law. Very most of them have exceptions, proverbially confirming the rule. There is almost always possible to find a scenario where a particular rule is not valid.

Answer (score 3):

Of course you can precipitate salt. Under pressure, the $\ce{HCl (aq)}$ could be far stronger, though it might not be completely ionized. However, that does not invalidate the equation, *per se*, other than that *some* of the product is $\ce{NaCl (aq)}$, and some $\ce{NaCl v}$.

This would be the same as the silver nitrate test for chlorine: $\ce{AgNO3 (aq) + NaCl(aq) -> NaNO3(aq) + AgCl v}$. $\ce{AgCl}$ is [**slightly** soluble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AgCl), 520 μg/100 g at 50 °C,  so the reaction actually can go backwards, but for convenience, it is written as if the precipitation were 100%.

Comment: But what you wrote in the first paragraph is, as I have indicated, precisely my point! Not everything stays ionised. Apart from that, up to boundary cases the silver nitrate test produces SOME AgCl if ANY NaCl is present, whereas if I mix my two solutions above, NaCl is only produced if their concentration was sufficiently high.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming we have $\pu{100 g}$ of $\pu{37\%}$ $\ce{HCl}$, e.g.  $\pu{37 g HCl}$ + $\pu{63 g}$ $\ce{H2O}$

The equivalent mass of NaOH:

$$m_\ce{NaOH}=\frac{M_\ce{NaOH}}{M_\ce{HCl}} \cdot m_\ce{HCl} 
\approx \frac{\pu{40 g mol-1}}{\pu{36.5 g mol-1}}\cdot \pu{37 g} \approx \pu{40.5 g } \ce{NaOH}$$

Solubility of $\ce{NaOH}$ is $$s= \dfrac{\pu{114 g } \ce{NaOH} }{ \pu{100 mL}} \approx  \dfrac{\pu{\pu{114 g} } \ce{NaOH} }{ \pu{100 g } \ce{H2O}}$$

The mass of water in $\ce{NaOH}$ solution is

$$m_\mathrm{\ce{H2O}\text{ in }\ce{NaOH}} = (\pu{40.5 g}) \frac{(\pu{100 g})}{(\pu{114 g})} \approx \pu{35.6 g } \ce{H2O}$$

We now sum water from HCl solution, from NaOH solkution and water from neutralization

$m_\mathrm{\ce{H2O},tot}=\pu{63 g} + \pu{35.5 g} + (\pu{40.5 g } \ce{NaOH}) \frac{M_\ce{H2O}}{M_\ce{NaOH}} = \\
= \pu{98.5 g} + \pu{40.5 g} \frac {\pu{18 g mol-1}}{\pu{40 g mol-1}}\approx 98.5 g + 18.2 g \approx \pu{116.7 g \ce{H2O}}$

There is formed $m_\ce{NaCl} = m_\ce{NaOH} \cdot \frac{M_\ce{NaCl}}{M_\ce{NaOH}} \approx \pu{40.5 g} \cdot \frac{\pu{58.5 g mol-1}}{\pu{40 g mol-1}} \approx \pu{59.2 g \ce{NaCl}}$

Now we have $\pu{59.2 g \pu{NaCl}}$ and $\pu{116.7 g \ce{H2O}}$, what gives approx. $\pu{50.8 g \ce{NaCl}}$ for $\pu{100 mL \ce{H2O}}$.

**As $50.8 \gt 36$, about 1/3 of $\ce{NaCl}$ would precipitate .**

Comment: I agree that your calculation is simpler. Kudos!

Answer (score 0):

So, the molar concentrations are as follows:

Suppose we got twice 50g water, and dissolve HCl in the first portion and NaOH in the second.

We know that we can dissolve at most 36g of salt in 100g of water. Salt is sodium chloride, and sodium has an atomic mass of about 23, whereas chlorine has about 35. This gives us about .62 mole of salt in the 136g solution.

So we would need to dissolve strictly more than .62 moles of NaOH and HCl in 50g of water.

NaOH has a total molecular mass of about 40, and HCl has about 36. Multiplied by .62 this makes about 25 and 22 respectively. These are precisely the grams of each substance we need to dissolve in 50g of water.

I conclude (22/72 ~= .31) that even using conventional methods, we could get solutions that are sufficiently concentrated.

All of this depends on the reaction processing the largest part of the educts.

If any of this sounds wrong, please downvote!

Comment: Hmm, I think you didn't account for water created in neutralisation.

Comment: Right. I'll correct this, but not this evening.

Answer (score -1):

RE:*So the question is: Can't I then produce highly concentrated solutions of sodium hydroxide and hydrochloric acid, so that upon mixing the two, some salt solidifies, because the resulting amount of salt is larger than what would be admissible in a saturated salt solution?*

Back of the envelope calculations say yes. However pragmatically don't try it experimentally without serious personal protection. Mixing highly concentrated $\ce{NaOH}$ solution with a highly concentrated $\ce{HCl}$ solution will create a lot of heat. Thus the solution is likely to "pop" and fling some of the concentrated solution around. Think of diluting concentrated sulfuric acid if you've ever done that.

Now for the calculations

**For** $\ce{NaCl}$

PubChem gives a solubility of [36.0 g/100 ml (25°C)](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/Sodium-Chloride#section=Solubility&fullscreen=true) and a density of [2.17 at 25°C](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/Sodium-Chloride#section=Density&fullscreen=true)

The weight percent of a saturated solution of $\ce{NaCl}$ is

$$\text{Wt% }\ce{NaCl} = \dfrac{36}{36+100} = 26.5\%$$

The molecular mass of $\ce{NaCl}$ is 58.4 grams/mole, so the solution is:

$$\dfrac{\ce{2170 x 0.265}}{58.4} = 9.84 \text{ molar}$$

In a liter of solution:

$$\text{g }\ce{NaCl} = \ce{2170 x 0.265} = 575$$

$$\text{g }\ce{H2O} = 2170 - 575 = 1595$$

**For** $\ce{NaOH}$

PubChem gives a solubility of [109 g per 100 ml water at 20°C:](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/14798#section=Solubility&fullscreen=true) as does the [Wikipedia Solubility Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solubility_table#S). Wikipedia also gives a solubility of 119 g per 100 ml at 30°C. Interpolating between the two Wikipedia values gives 114 g /100 ml at 25°C. PubChem gives a density of [2.13 g/cu cm 25°C](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/14798#section=Density&fullscreen=true)

The weight percent of a saturated solution of $\ce{NaOH}$ is

$$\text{Wt% }\ce{NaOH} = \dfrac{114}{114+100} = 53.3\%$$

The molecular mass of $\ce{NaCl}$ is 40.0 grams/mole, so the solution is:

$$\dfrac{\ce{2130 x 0.533}}{40.0} = 28.4 \text{ molar}$$

In a liter of solution:

$$\ce{\text{g }\ce{NaOH} = \ce{2130 x 0.533} = 1135}$$

$$\ce{\text{g }\ce{H2O} = 2130 - 1135 = 995}$$

**For** $\ce{HCl}$

Wikipedia states that a 37% solution is [12.4 molar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrochloric_acid) and has a density of 1.189 kg/L. The MW of $\ce{HCl = 36.5}$.

In a liter of solution:

$$\text{g }\ce{HCl} = \ce{12.4 x 36.5 = 453}$$

$$\text{g }\ce{H2O} = \ce{1189 - 453 = 736}$$

Thus stoichiometrically about 1.00 Liter concentrated $\ce{NaOH}$ will be neutralized by 2.28 Liters of concentrated $\ce{HCl}$.

The neutralization creates roughly $28.4$ moles of water which is about 511 ml of water.

So 1.00 liters of concentrated $\ce{NaOH}$,  mixed with 2.28 Liters of concentrated $\ce{HCl}$ will have 28.4 moles $\ce{NaCl}$ and:

$$\text{g }\ce{H2O} = \ce{995 + 736 x 2.28 + 511 = 3184}$$

$$\text{g }\ce{NaCl} = \ce{28.4 x 58.4 =  1658}$$

Per 100 ml of water

$$\text{g }\ce{NaCl} = \dfrac{1658}{31.84} = 52.1$$

This exceeds the PubChem given solubility of [36.0 g/100 ml (25°C)](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/Sodium-Chloride#section=Solubility&fullscreen=true) so $\ce{52.1 - 36.0 = 16.1 g}$ per 100 ml of water must precipitate.

Comment: While diluting concentrated sulfuric acid in the sink I had a beaker get so hot that it cracked due to stress (scratch on glass, temperature differential- whatever). Fortunately I could just quickly flush the mess down the sink with lots and lots of water.